# Why does the y-axis of one of my objects appear to be backwards?

Tags: coordinates

My Transform Orientation is set to local. I have this object that when highlight is using a right hand co-ordinate system (z up, x forward, y orthogonal to the x-z plane):

[image: Right hand coordinate system]

I click on another object and the transform looks like this:

[image]

Which is not right handed. How do I reset this object to use right handed coordinates? I'm not sure what I did to make it like this. It's like the Y axis is backwards. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a negative scale - see the Scale panel on the right-hand side. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and Apply Scale and the transform should behave as you expect. You may also need to Recalculate Normals once you've applied the scale in case any are left pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. This was the problem, I applied your solution and I'm back in business.

Answer (score 2):

The second object is scaled to negative values (see the "scale" information in the properties tab). Simply scale it back again to change the local coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

The second object you have selected is rotated 180 degrees around the y axis; you can press Ctrl+A -> apply rotation and it should zero out.

Comment: I tried that but it is still the same problem. Even if I rotate it back around the Y axis or apply the rotation, the Y axis is still pointing in the opposite direction to the other object. I'm at a loss on how to "flip" the y axis to be orthogonal to the other side of the x-z- plane.